# Integral of product of Bessel functions

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I have the following integral
$$\int_{x=0}^\infty \frac{x^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{x^2+a^2} \,  \mathrm{J}_{\frac{3}{2}}(b \, x) \, \mathrm{J}_{0}(c \, x) \, \mathrm{d}x\ $$

with $a^2 \in \mathbb{C}$,  $\, b>0$ and $c>0$.

I can solve the integral for $c>b$, any ideas how to solve it for $c<b$.

Thank you.

Edit:
The solution for the first case can be given with the general formula
$$\int_{x=0}^\infty \frac{x^{\mu-\nu+2\ell+1}}{x^2+a^2} \,  \mathrm{J}_{\mu}(b \, x) \, \mathrm{J}_{\nu}(c \, x) \, \mathrm{d}x\  = (-1)^\ell \, a^{\mu-\nu+2\ell} \, \mathrm{K}_{\mu}(b \, a) \, \mathrm{I}_{\nu}(c \, a)$$
with $-(\ell+1)<\mathrm{Re}(\mu)<\mathrm{Re}(\nu)-2\ell+2$ and $b>c$.

Comment: How can you solve it for  $c>b$? Also notice that one parameter among $\{a,b,c\}$ is redundant since you may remove it through a suitable substitution.

Comment: The solution for the first case is given with $\mu=0$, $\nu=\frac{3}{2}$ and $\ell=0$. ($b$ and $c$ are interchanged).

Comment: What's your source for said general formula?

Comment: The general formula is presented in http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11139-013-9529-4. Sadly it is not open access.

Comment: Page 49 of volume 2 of Erdelyi's "Table of Integrals" (available online [here](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/7/Volume%202.pdf) seems like a good reference here. (Be sure to examine the headings of the tables before interpreting them.)

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I had this one already, but it still does not solve the second case...

Comment: You're right: I hadn't realized that formulas (12) and (14) were just duplicates of one another, and so don't contain the desired case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44003/discussion-between-semiclassical-and-mk12).

Answer (score 1):

Your integral can be written as

$$I(a,b,c)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi b^3}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{-bx\cos(bx)+\sin(bx)}{x^2(a^2+x^2)}\, J_0(cx)\,dx \tag{1}$$
and the last integral can be computed by switching to Fourier transforms: the Fourier transform of $J_0(cx)$ is a multiple of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2-s^2}}$ supported on $(-c,c)$ and the Fourier transform of the other term is tedious but straightforward to compute.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can compute the Fourier Transforms of both terms, but how will this lead to a closed form solution? Convolution?

Comment: One potential issue: While the integral with both terms together appears to be convergent, each term on its own appears to diverge (according to Mathematica). The Fourier approach may avoid this, but it suggests that things are a bit delicate.

Comment: @Semiclassical: yes, we have to be careful in dealing with cancellations. Another chance is to use the Laplace transform through $$\mathcal{L}\, J_0(x)=\frac{1}{ \sqrt{1+s^2}},$$ but it is more or less the same.

Comment: I am still not aware how to use this information to evaluate the integral. Can you give me a hint or a reference? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @MK12: if you are not fluent in the use of the Fourier (or Laplace) transform, what is the point of estimating integrals involving multiple Bessel functions?

Comment: Do you mean Parseval's theorem? Do you think the integrals are simpler in the transformed domain?